# How to split particular words in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to split this statement in Lua

```
sendex,000D6F0011BA2D60,fb,btn,1,on,100,null
```

i need output like this way:

```
Mac:000D6F0011BA2D60
Value:1
command:on
value:100
```

how to split and get the values?

Comment: Is your input always 8 elements, separated by commas? And do you always put the 2nd, 5th, 6th and 7th elements in your output? We need to know how your inputs should map to your outputs in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
local input = "sendex,000D6F0011BA2D60,fb,btn,1,on,100,null"
local buffer = {}
for word in input:gmatch('[^,]+') do
  table.insert(buffer, word)
  --print(word) -- uncomment this to see the words as they are being matched ;)
end
print("Mac:"..buffer[2])
print("Value:"..buffer[5])
...
```

For a complete explanation of what `string.gmatch` does, see the [Lua reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch). To summarize, it iterates over a string and searches for a pattern, in this case `[^,]+`, meaning all groups of 1 or more characters that aren't a comma. Every time it finds said pattern, it does something with it and continues searching.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is exactly like you have described, the code below works:

```
s="sendex,000D6F0011BA2D60,fb,btn,1,on,100,null"
Mac,Value,command,value = s:match(".-,(.-),.-,.-,(.-),(.-),(.-),")
print(Mac,Value,command,value)
```

It uses the non-greedy pattern `.-` to split the input into fields. It also captures the relevant fields.